# I'm getting an error when I use PyInstaller to convert my gTTS project to an EXE

Tags: python, pyinstaller, gtts

I'm just making a Python console app that converts text to an mp3 file.

This is my Python code :

```py
from gtts import gTTS
import os


text=input() 

mp3 = gTTS(text = text,lang='en',slow=False)

mp3.save("testfile.mp3")

os.system("testfile.mp3")

# enter to exit 
input()
```

When I run this using VSCode it works perfectly.
However when I'm running it after I convert it to an EXE it just says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speak-a-tron.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtts'
[8212] Failed to execute script 'speak-a-tron' due to unhandled exception!

[process exited with code 1]
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you.

PS:- I just saw this line of text when I converted my `.py` file to a `.exe` file: `7332 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python38.dll` though I'm using Python 3.10.
Plus I saw this txt file in my BUILD folder :

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported from within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
           yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), distutils.util (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named org - imported by copy (optional)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), shutil (conditional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), test.support (optional)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (optional), multiprocessing.util (delayed)
missing module named _posixshmem - imported by multiprocessing.resource_tracker (conditional), multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio (delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
missing module named pyimod03_importers - imported by C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py (top-level)
missing module named gtts - imported by C:\Users\User\Desktop\speak-a-tron.py (top-level)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PyInstaller can't find the `gtts` module. As noted in the ["When Things Go Wrong"](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules) section of the documentation, you could try using the command line option [`-p DIR`/`-paths DIR`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-p) in order to specify additional paths to search for modules.